# Possible Race Condition in Singleton Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, race-condition

I am running into what appears to be a race condition in a Spring bean that is called from a third party library and I am trying to determine if there is an issue with my implementation or if the issue is possibly with the third party library

```
@Override
public InputObject addMessageToInput(InputObject input) {

    List<String> messages = doStuff();

    log.debug("Messages are {}", messages);//messages appear to be correct at this point

    doLongRunningOpertation(); 

    log.debug("Messages are {}", messages);//messages appear to be correct at this point
    input.addMessages(messages);

    return input; //Return to third party library here
}
```

Upon return of this function the third party library handles displaying messages to the front end. The issue that I am seeing is that the messages displayed on the front end sometimes include extra or fewer messages than they should. I should also note that the program is NOT multi threaded.

Is there anything I am missing in my code that could be causing this race condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there can be lots of things happening, but I think your code looks pretty ok.

Somethings to consider...

Does the `messages` list get passed around at all in the `doLongRunningOperation()` method?  If so, is it being placed into a class variable at anypoint?

Is the `InputObject` a new object every time it is passed into your code?  If not, then that could cause issues.

Is the `InputObject` `messages` variable empty when it comes into your code?

You could consider returning a new instance of `InputObject` instead of using the instance that is sent to your method.

You could comment out the long running process to see if the problem keeps happening.

If you can see the problem repeat in your particular development environment you could put a debug breakpoint in the `InputObject.addMessages()` method and see when it is getting called.

Just some ideas to think about and perhaps try to help debug the problem.

Comment: Another thought...  Perhaps the `InputObject` `messages` variable is being manipulated outside of the `InputObject`.  I have seen that happen before too.  Meaning that the messages collection returned from InputObject is mutable instead of immutable and some code is interacting with that reference.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer since it helped my determine with more certainty that the issue was not in the code posted above. The actual issue ended up being with how the third party library was displaying messages to user who had multiple active sessions.